# In VBA, value from table not converting to date for evaluation

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA. Always get hung up on these data type errors!

Basically, a date value coming from a table is identified as a string. But when I try to convert either by CDate or by DateValue, I get an error:

```
Dim i As Integer
    With mlist
    For i = 1 To .ListRows.Count
        Dim c As Range
        Set c = ows.Range("AE:AE").Find(.DataBodyRange(i, 7).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        MsgBox VarType(c.Offset(0, 10).Value)
        MsgBox VarType(DateValue(.DataBodyRange(0, 11).Value))
```

Here the first message box evaluates to 7, a date data type which is correct.
The second message, as is, gives an error, even though the VarType function returns an 8 (a string data type) when evaluating `.DataBodyRange(0, 11).Value`

For some reason I can't convert `.DataBodyRange(0, 11).Value` into a date value!

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Why are you using `c.Offset(0, 10)` and then `.DataBodyRange(0, 11)`? What does `MsgBox .DataBodyRange(0, 11).Value` return?

Comment: `.DataBodyRange(0, 11)` would be a cell in the table header, or at least in the same row on the sheet as the table header row. Is that what you expect?

Comment: Hi @BigBen! You are absolutely right. In the back and forth, copy pasting trying to figure it out I must have overlooked this. It seems to be evaluating correctly now. Thank you for all your help as always.